# Help with intent starting on Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-layout

I am trying to learn a few things from http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/checkout. I wanted to see how they implemented that UI patterns they were talking about on the I/O.

In the *HomeActivity* they use this code to fire up the *NotesActivity* :

```
/* Launch list of notes user has taken*/
public void onNotesClick(View v) {  
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Notes.CONTENT_URI));
}
```

Notes class is in the ScheduleContract class and it looks like :

```
public static class Notes implements NotesColumns, BaseColumns {
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI =
            BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(PATH_NOTES).build();
    public static final Uri CONTENT_EXPORT_URI =
            CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(PATH_EXPORT).build();

    /** {@link Sessions#SESSION_ID} that this note references. */
    public static final String SESSION_ID = "session_id";

    /** Default "ORDER BY" clause. */
    public static final String DEFAULT_SORT = NotesColumns.NOTE_TIME + " DESC";

    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE =
            "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.iosched.note";
    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE =
            "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.iosched.note";

    public static Uri buildNoteUri(long noteId) {
        return ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, noteId);
    }

    public static long getNoteId(Uri uri) {
        return ContentUris.parseId(uri);
    }
}
```

I cant see what exactly this code do, and how it ends up starting *NotesActivity* with notes loaded in. I also dont understand how and for what is URI used as a second parameter in new :
    Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Notes.CONTENT_URI).
I searched on Google for explanation but failed to find simple one and simple examples. I would guess that *Notes* class is used to point to and format the data (notes) and then somehow *NotesActivity* is started, but dont understand exactly how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android you never launch a specific application, at least not directly. What you do, is that you create an [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html), which is `an abstract description of an operation to be performed`:

> An Intent provides a facility for
>   performing late runtime binding
>   between the code in different
>   applications. Its most significant use
>   is in the launching of activities,
>   where it can be thought of as the glue
>   between activities. It is basically a
>   passive data structure holding an
>   abstract description of an action to
>   be performed. The primary pieces of
>   information in an intent are:
>
> - **action** -- The general action to
>     be performed, such as
>     [ACTION_VIEW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW), [ACTION_EDIT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_EDIT),
>     [ACTION_MAIN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MAIN), etc.
> - **data** -- The data to operate on,
>     such as a person record in the
>     contacts database, expressed as a
>     [Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html).

Whenever you want to launch another application, send a text message, pick a contact, activate the camera etc, you just create and start an `Intent`, and then Android figures out by itself what application it should launch.

So for your example with the Notes activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Notes.CONTENT_URI));
```

The first parameter, `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`, tells that this `Intet`will display something to the user. The second parameter, `Notes.CONTENT_URI`, is the Uniform Resource Identifier for the Notes activity (in your example, the URI can also include an ID if you want to open the activity with a specific note). The result is that the Notes activity is displayed for the user.

If you need more information, I suggest reading about [Android Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) and [Intents and Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html), which explain these concepts in detail

Comment: Thanks, I connected the basics of Intent using. In my example above, they are using content provider and URI is pointing to the notes stored in that provider.